# Möbius maps and their fixed points

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Why is it true that if a Möbius map, $f(z)$ fixes distinct $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb C_\infty$ that $f(z)$ either describes a rotation or has a pair of stable and unstable fixed points, such that iterations of $f(z)$ converges to the stable fixed point for $z\neq$ the unstable fixed point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fairly standard argument is to conjugate with a Moebius transformation that sends $0$ to $z_1$ and $\infty$ to $z_2$.  This gives you a Moebius transformation that fixes $0$ and $\infty$.  A little algebra tells you this is just the map $z \longmapsto az$ for some complex number $a$.

Comment: Thank you! How did you come up with it?

Comment: Conjugation of a map is essentially the equivalent of a coordinate change.  When you talk about "rotation about fixed points", that can be interpreted as "in certain coordinates the map looks like $z \longmapsto az$".  So the type of your question basically leads one to think: conjugation.

Comment: Thanks, just curious what is the coordinate system we end up working in?

Comment: I'm a little confused now.  I'm not saying it *is* a coordinate change, but it's analogous.  Just look through what one does in other context when one makes a coordinate change, like representing a matrix with respect to another basis, for example.  That produces a conjugation.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you Ryan.